# Compare attribute DataAnnotations not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I can't get the compare attribute working when I validate an object by hand. I've made a simple test console application that also doesn't work. Do I somethin wrong?

I use the newest version of the .Net Framework 4.5.1. 
I made this console test application because it's also not working in my MVC application that executes the dataannotations in the business layer (seperate class library).

Thanks.

The class to test:

```
public class Change // : IValidatableObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The current password of this account.
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Huidig wachtwoord is verplicht")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string CurrentPassword { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The new password for the logged in user account.
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wachtwoord is verplicht")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This must be the same as <see cref="NewPassword"/>.
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bevestig wachtwoord is verplicht")]
    [Compare("NewPassword")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string NewPassword2 { get; set; }

    //public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    //{
    //    return new List<ValidationResult>();
    //}
}
```

The console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var change = new Change()
        {
            CurrentPassword = "ABC",
            NewPassword = "123",
            NewPassword2 = "12345678"
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Initial values:");
        Console.WriteLine("NewPassword: " + change.NewPassword);
        Console.WriteLine("NewPassword Confirm: " + change.NewPassword2);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Let's see if the compare attribute works...");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();

        try
        {
            Validator.ValidateObject(change, new ValidationContext(change, null, null));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();

            throw ex;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Validation doesn't work because you see this line.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Adding the `IValidatableObject` also doesn't work.

Comment: I did find another bug in the Compare attribute that isn't release yet with the NuGet packages on this moment. https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the other overload of `Validator.ValidateObject` that takes a `Boolean` argument to validate all properties:

```
public static void ValidateObject(
  Object instance,
  ValidationContext validationContext,
  bool validateAllProperties
)
```

*Ref: [Validator.ValidateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382100%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*

Example:

```
try
{
  Validator.ValidateObject(change, new ValidationContext(change, null, null), true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  Console.ReadLine();

  throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the true does? Why is the required attribute working without the overload with true and the compare not?

Comment: Oh I see in the TryValidate documentation on MSDN that if you don't use the true overload, only the required attributes are validated

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 private List<ValidationResult> ValidateModel(object model)
        {
            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var ctx = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
            Validator.TryValidateObject(model, ctx, validationResults, true);
            return validationResults;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling Validator.ValidateObject(change, new ValidationContext(change), true) works for me, the boolean tells the Validator to validate all properties.